# How to find the best player everyday in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | name   | country     | score | email        | timestamp           |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
|  2 | John   | Canada      |   360 | john@abc.com | 2015-01-28 14:23:35 |
|  3 | Peter  | USA         |   830 | NULL         | 2015-01-28 16:23:35 |
|  4 | Victor | New Zealand |   780 | NULL         | 2015-01-27 06:33:55 |
|  5 | Sandy  | UK          |   880 | NULL         | 2015-01-29 02:09:58 |
|  6 | Craig  | New Zealand |   980 | NULL         | 2015-01-29 02:11:26 |
|  7 | Susan  | New Zealand |   580 | NULL         | 2015-01-29 02:11:57 |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
```

The table name 'scores' and I would like to find out who is the best player on each day? I'm a totally newbie in mysql. Therefore, if someone could guild me the way to find out who is the best player on each day in mysql will be a greatly appreciated!

The result, I would like to achieve is only shown the best player on each day like this:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | name   | country     | score | email        | timestamp           |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
|  6 | Craig  | New Zealand |   980 | NULL         | 2015-01-29 02:11:26 |
|  3 | Peter  | USA         |   830 | NULL         | 2015-01-28 16:23:35 |
|  4 | Victor | New Zealand |   780 | NULL         | 2015-01-27 06:33:55 |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Lots of info left out, and you should have at least made an attempt. Roughly something like `select id, name, country, score, email, timestamp from table_name order by score desc limit 1`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried that, but the result is shown up all the players. I need only the best player of the day. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use aggregation and a join:

```
select t.*
from scores t join
     (select date(timestamp) as dte, max(score) as maxscore
      from scores t
      group by date(timestamp)
     ) tt
     on tt.dte = date(t.timestamp) and tt.maxscore = t.score;
```

Note:  if you have duplicates, this will return all people who have the same maximum score.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can you explain a little bit more for above query since I'm a noob in mysql? What is t? Assume I had a table name called 'scores'. What should I do to fit to your code?